# module not found - even when in correct file order

Tags: f#

I am working on an f# project for Android. I am somewhat familiar with both, but I am running into an issue where the compiler seems to be unaware of my image helper module and I've been unable to find an answer as to why. I greatly appreciate any feedback.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the file order in the fsproj file. Sometimes they get out of sync.

Comment: Try to move your helper file down and then up again (ALT + Arrows) in Solution Explorer.